# Untupling a function

Tags: f#, higher-order-functions

Suppose I want to run a fold using a function that expects a tuple, f (x, y). This can be done with

```
List.fold (fun x y -> f (x, y)) x xs
```

I kind of feel there ought to be a higher-order function that abstracts out that pattern, takes a function that expects a tuple and turns it into a function that expects two separate arguments.

Is there such a function in the F# standard library? If not, easy enough to write but what should it idiomatically be called? `untuple`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That function is normally called [curry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry) in most functional languages. It's definition is:

```
let curry f x y = f (x, y)
```

Unfortunately it's not in the F# core lib, but it's available in many external base libraries, like [F#x](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/0c34475e5e0a0217bae7c5e65271f4410e6c8bf4/src/FSharpx.Extras/Prelude.fs) and [F#+](https://github.com/gusty/FSharpPlus).